# What would be a generic formula to get the final output of a number if it was increased by a specific percent for a specific number of times?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, percentages

A positive number x was increased by y% for k times. What should be a generic formula for the same so that we get the correct final value for any positive number increased by any %, any number of times?
E.g. If we increase 2 by 10% for 2 times, then:

```
result:  2 + 10%(2) + 10%(2 + 10%(2))
      :  2 + (1/5) + (11/50)
      :  121/50
```

Similarly if we, let's say, want to increase 15 by 25% for 38 times, it will be difficult and time consuming to find the result if we calculate as in the above process. A generic formula would be a faster way. I don't know if it will be similar to compound interest.

Comment: *A positive number x was increased by y% for k times.*

Then the final value is$$\left(\frac{y+100}{100}\right)^kx.$$

This is indeed essentially the compound-interest formula.